# Radius of convergence: $\sum(a_k(z+3i)^k)$ and $\sum(1-(-2)^{n})(z+i \sqrt{2})^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I have stumbled on the following mock questions. I know how to solve these type when it is of the form $a_nz^n$ but don't have an ideia what to do with these. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Find the radius of convergence

$\sum(a_k(z+3i)^k)$ with $a_{2m-1}=\frac1m$, $a_{2m} = 1$, $m \in \Bbb N$.

$\sum(1-(-2)^{n})(z+i \sqrt{2})^n$ with $a_{2m-1}=1/m$, $a_{2m} = 1$, m belongs to N.